# handle firebird events asynchronously with perl

Tags: perl, events, asynchronous, firebird

I'm creating an info board app with data taken from firebird 1.5 database.
I would like not to use polling but events.

I've created sample trigger which fires up an event in firebird database.
Now I need a client to listen for and handle the event.
I've decided to go with perl.
Here is the doc [DBD::Firebird](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Firebird/Firebird.pm#EVENT_ALERT_SUPPORT).
I'm trying to go with async events.

Here's the code, I give the skeleton which won't work anyway.

The event won't fire up in perl. What am I doing wrong. Please help, thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;

$dsn =<< "DSN";
dbi:Firebird:dbname=/home/firebird/dev/db.gdb;
host=localhost;
port=3050;
ib_dialect=3;
DSN

$dbh =  DBI->connect($dsn, "user", "password");

# events of interest
@event_names = ("schedule_event");

$evh = $dbh->func(@event_names, 'ib_init_event');

my $cb = sub {.
    print "got event";
};

$dbh->func($evh, $cb, 'ib_register_callback');

while (1) {
}
```

UPDATE:
ok here's the php script I'm going with right now, just leave it here maybe it helps someone:

```
<?php

declare(ticks = 1);

$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$host = 'localhost:/home/firebird/base/base.gdb';
$sockets = array();

$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);

function event_handler($event_name, $link) {
    echo $event_name . "\n";
    send_message($event_name);
}

# we need to unregister event in firebird before exit
function terminate($signal) {
    global $event;
    if (is_null($event)) {
        die ( "no event has been registered yet, exiting" );
    } else {
        ibase_free_event_handler($event);
        die ( "unregistered evented and exiting\n" );
    }
}

function send_message($msg)
{
    $localsocket = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8010';
    $instance = stream_socket_client ($localsocket, $errno, $errstr);
    fwrite($instance, json_encode(['message' => $msg, 'userId' => 824])  . \n");
}

$event = ibase_set_event_handler($dbh, "event_handler", "schedule_update");

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "terminate");

while (true) {
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Comment: Note: Always put `use strict; use warnings;` after shebang.

Comment: ok, but that won't help :-) I need some kind of proper main loop or smth.

Comment: How do you trigger the event? Make sure that you commit, as events are only fired on commit of the transaction, not at the moment you raise it.

Comment: Mark, you were right, I've fixed the problem, now the event is being sent to perl client. But now the perl script fails with segfault. The same functionality php script works though. I'm using [link]http://php.net/manual/ru/book.ibase.php

Comment: I don't know perl, but callbacks from the native client library can be troublesome. When rewriting the native implementation in Jaybird I also had some segfaults because I was handling the pointers and the reference to the callback function incorrectly.